# Snowflake performance tuning columns with high cardinality

Tags: sql, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can we make the queries like below faster in snowflake.

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC 
FROM TableA 
WHERE ColumnA = 'ABC123'

SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC 
FROM TableA 
WHERE ColumnA IN ('ABC123', 'ABC456', 'ABCnnn')
```

Table A has 500 million rows, 200 columns, 30GB compressed size and column A has 300 million unique values.

`ColumnA` cannot be used as the clustering key as the table is already clustered by other column which is necessary. Also, search optimization is already switched on for the table.

A typical query with 15K values in IN clause returns results in 30 seconds with XL warehouse, whereas the legacy datastores which are indexed on these columns results in 1 sec.

Comment: 15k values in an IN clause may actually be creating a high compile time for you, rather than the execution time.  How much time is compile vs. execution?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, a join key that is a string, is bad for performance.
But an `IN` clauses with 15K values is worse. 200 columns is not that ideal ether.

I suspect this will not be the case, but if the query that needs speeding up is only three columns, I would make a second table with only those three columns, and then do multi-table updates/inserts, when upserting to keep them in sync.

With 15K values in a IN clause you are doing a full table scan, thus your time will be completely IO bound, and you should find you get something like ~40MBps per instance, thus to read it faster (this was the number I recall we used to notice our big IO bound tasks took), will need larger instances. But that leaves you with a constant cost.

To avoid a full table scan you somehow need to let Snowflake help you avoid some data (if you are selecting 3/200 columns, that is some reduction). So this is ether done via clustering on you key, or limiting the data by some other criteria like insertion time. or some other filters that can drop rows.

If there is nothing that you can pre-filter that data on, then you are in the joyous place of full table scans.

Comment: Rather than creating a separate table, you could create an MV for this, as well.  This will make it stay in sync without any work AND you can continue to reference the base table and allow the automatic query rewrite functionality do the work for you (choosing the MV).

Comment: Agreed, a Materialized View can achieve the same effect. At two levels of cost, one is how the Materialization is happening "auto-magic" and thus like all magic, might not align well with the reality of your data, and read/write patterns. But it sure is simpler starting point. I guess I tend to lean into having a deeper understanding on your complete data flow, and thus writing the data in ways that allow the usage you need. MV are a tool to help with that.

Comment: @MikeWalton hmm, the auto SQL rewrite is a new advantage I did not know about. That does sound rather nice.

Comment: It is fairly new and IMO it's a bit buried in the docs.  It doesn't always work as you'd expect, but in this case (3 of 200 columns), it would definitely work even when querying the base table.

Comment: Also, as a note, you can also cluster the MV on the ColumnA (or a substring of it would be best), which could then also improve pruning of the MV.  This may create some churn in the clustering service between the base table and the MV, but might be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake uses micro-partitioning as its hybrid partitioning technology; what you are describing here may be more of a data architecture / modelling limitation.

For sure as the others have commented, 15k search keys in the IN clause is a bad idea --- if you think internally it needs to parse 15,000 search values to the static pruning step and this will lead to a long compilation time. We often recommend to not do that that maybe a better solution would be to include those 15,000 values in a separate table and include it in an INNER JOIN. This is dynamic pruning and needed for such a requirement to find so many matches.

Snowflake is Deep Right Join Tree optimised meaning that if the above content is a part of a Star-Join query then performance might even be faster!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Enterprise Edition or above, you could try
[Search Optimization](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service.html)

Comment: Looks like the OP already stated they have Search Optimization turned on.